# Declaring queries in global variables

Tags: c++, mysql, optimization, global-variables, query-optimization

I'm currently remaking code and there's a lot of queries written in global variables, but i noticed that some of these queries are used only once. I'm assuming that second method will be better for that queries. I'm right? Also second method uses less memory or no difference?

**Current method (using global variable):**

```
char g_query[] = "SELECT %s FROM %s WHERE %s >= %i";
void func()
{
    printf(g_query, "name", "table", "something", 1);
}
```

**Second method (without using global variable):**

```
void func()
{
    printf("SELECT %s FROM %s WHERE %s >= %i",  "name", "table", "something", 1);
}
```

Comment: Look at the assembly.  Depending on the usage, the optimizer, and how much you optimize the code, you could get the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are both very naughty. We don't embed queries like that in code anymore.

Used a parameterised query instead or a stored procedure.

Otherwise you are vulnerable to SQL injection attack and other nasties.

As for the speed, the bottleneck will be in the acquisition of data, let alone in the fashioning of the string in the `printf` call. Don't let the performance aspect of using a global variable or otherwise influence your design decisions.

Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: I know about SQL injection, that was just simple example, but thanks for explaining that.